# Extract the value from an array in Apache NiFi

Tags: json, text, apache-nifi

I have a JSON with this structure:

```json
{
  "documentos": [
    {
      "valorNota": 229.2,
      "tipoDocumento": "PRE_NOTA_FISCAL",
      "cnpjEmissorNota": "02130525000177",
      "cnpjRemetente": "02130525000177",
      "cnpjUnidade": "02130525000177",
      "cnpjDestinatario": "14586674000124",
      "valorFreteRealizadoNota": 0,
      "serie": "1",
      "valorFreteCalculadoNota": 1000,
      "tipoOperacao": "SAIDA",
      "dataEmissao": "2022-12-05 11:03:00",
      "numeroNota": 744659
    }
  ],
  "dataEmissaoConhecimento": "2022-12-05 11:03:00.0",
  "localizacaoDestinoConhecimento": 3002171,
  "localizacaoOrigemConhecimento": 3001956,
  "cepOrigemConhecimento": 44079006,
  "cepDestinoConhecimento": 48880000,
  "valorFreteRealizadoConhecimento": 0,
  "oidConhecimento": 10802880097,
  "valorFreteCalculadoConhecimento": 1000
}
```

I need to extract the value of `"numeroNota"` (can be with ***EvaluateJsonPath*** or other processor).

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: EvaluateJsonPath processor -> `$.documentos[*].numeroNota`

Comment: You can try here, https://jsonpath.com/

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a **shift** transformation spec within a ***JoltTransformJSON*** processor such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "docu*": { //the level of "documentos" array
        "*": { //the indexes of the array
          "numeroN*": "" //yields the value of the attribute without any wrapper
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

which returns **744659** as result for the current case